# .flg File Extension on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, files

Can someone please explain to me what are .flg files and why they might be used for on Windows Machines (servers). I have been googling for it, but can´t find relevant infos. I found the files on servers that are supporting cash registers.

Comment: Found in a not-shared folder ? Check in add/remove software, it's one of them

Answer (score 0):

Would be usefull to know in which folder you found them. In general *.flg (FSCK.flg or FSCKME.flg) are used by Puppy Linux. For example FSCKME.flg is a flagging system to start a file system check, if it is found during the startup boot.

> /etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit creates /fsckme.flg at bootup

It is removed in the shutdown, if the shutdown is correct:

> rc.shutdown deletes it

See [here](http://barryk.org/fossil/woof2.cgi/vinfo/6ddf124baf) and also [whats the fsckme.flg and what does it do?](http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=65301)

So the only reason why you see them on a Windows OS is, that they belong to an Puppy Linux OS used there as well (e.g. maybe a multiboot OS)